# Polymorphism and abstract parent class

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstract

In the practice I am doing now I have 3 classes in the hierarchy:
**Employee** (abstract class)
**Worker** extends Employee
**Manager** extends Employee

I have an additional class who uses those 3 classes: **Factory**.

I have to build now a method which adds an Employee e to an array of Employees.
Attributes:

_emps - an array of type **Employee**.
_numOfEmpes - indicates the number of employess in the array.

This is the code I wrote:

```
public boolean addEmployee(Employee e){
    if (this._numOfEmps<MAX_EMPS)
    {
        this._emps[this._numOfEmps]=e;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that I think that by the row:

```
this._emps[this._numOfEmps]=e;
```

I create an array of alias objects, which I am not sure is what I have to do.
What I usually have done is:

```
this._emps[this._numOfEmps)=new Employee(e);
```

But since Employee class is abstract I can't do that.

This is a polymorphism practice, so I guess the professor wanted us to put Workers and Managers in the array, but I can't add Workers and Managers to the array in the method.

Any help will be great,

Thank you.

Comment: You should make the array of type `Employee`. This way, you can put any classes in it which **extend** `Employee`.

Comment: I have, and it does work, however I am worried if the aliasing I create here is not a problem.

Comment: Arrays in java are polymorphically covariant. This means that an array that is declared to hold Employee class objects will be able to handle all it's sub classes.

Comment: @Assaf what kind of problems do you expect?

Comment: @LukasKnuth I just don't really know when aliasing is OK and when it is not. I guess that now it is just ok, considering the current practice. Thank you

Comment: @Assaf it depends on what your class does. If it's a simple data-encapsulation class, you should make it **immutable**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's perfectly OK to create an array of reference objects. There should be no problem with that.

However, if you want to create copies, then check the `clone` method, implement it and use it in `addEmployee`.

Here is an example of how to implement Cloneable - http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/cloning.php

Then

```
this._emps[this._numOfEmps]=e.clone();
++this._numOfEmps;
```

Comment: [Don't use `clone()` for defensive copies!](http://codeisland.org/2012/rules-of-immutability/#dont-use-clone-for-defensive-copies)